# Given $f''(x)<0\text{ for }a<x\leq b$, prove $f'(a)>\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\text{ for }a<x\leq b$

Tags: calculus

I've been working on a problem and I reduced it down to this inequality which I cannot solve.

Given $f(x)$ which is continuous on the interval $a\leq x\leq b$ and $$f''(x)<0\text{ for }a<x\leq b$$

Prove: $$f'(a)>\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\text{ for }a<x\leq b$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there is $y\in (a,x)$, such that 
$$f^\prime(y) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
The claim now follows since $f^\prime$ is decreasing by the assumption $f^{\prime\prime}<0$.

Comment: My bad, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

We have from the Taylor Formula with a Remainder that there exists a $\xi$ with $a<\xi<x\le b$ such that

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12f''(\xi)(x-a)^2$$

Rearranging reveals that

$$f'(a)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=-\frac12f''(\xi)(x-a)>0$$

and we're done!